# P to P assists exchange

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

We are building a POC with P2P interaction. It’s a prototype were 2 parties agree to exchange assets and the settlement is done.

For above POC is it good to use global agreement contract or have individual deal level contracts.

Comment: What do you mean by > is it good to use global agreement contract or have individual deal level contracts.

Comment: Should we use a single contract and create object of it for each deal or for each deal deploy individual contract

Comment: As long as the exchange is fairly straightforward, I don't see why it'd make it easier to split the contracts. I'm interested in what others would have to say.

Comment: 1. If multiple people what’s to access the same contract what will be the impact on throughput. 
2. There is no data isolation.

Comment: I guess there could be different interpretations for data isolation, but I don't think ethereum has or plans to have data isolation in the traditional sense. Until zkSnarks is added, any data on the blockchain is publically visible. There shouldn't really be an impact on throughput, either. Are you planning on using a multi sig? You'd get better help from others here, by the way. :)

Comment: + I haven't looked into how miners choose transactions, or what they ideal gas price of a contract is (to be included in the next block), but so long as it's below the gas limit you should be fine. http://ethgasstation.info/ is fairly useful, in this regard.

Comment: It will be more efficient to use one contract. As @DakotaQuint there's really no data isolation on the blockchain.

Comment: @TjadenHess is there any technical advantage of using a single contract or cost is the factor ?